# New form show as sidebar from main form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

When I click on the button, I want to show the second `Form` like a side bar to right edge of my first form. How can I do that?

```
namespace testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Came out as slide bar*?

Comment: Maybe you mean sidebar?!

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes sidebar

Comment: If want a sidebar effect, why not use a [SplitContainer Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) in the main form and expand/collapse  its Panel2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to code the `Move` and `Resize` events to adapt the other form. If both shall be able to be moved, always sticking together, you need to code the events for both; try to not create an endless loop ;-)

Here is an example:

```
private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // you may or may not need this flag
   // you would set and clear in the form's constructor and at the end of the Load event.
    if (loading) return; 
    placeForm2();
}

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    placeForm2();
}

public void placeForm2()
{
    form2.Top = this.Top;
    form2.Left = this.Left + this.Width;

    int sw = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Width;
    int sh = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Height;

    if (form2.Right >= sw) form2.Left = this.Left - form2.Width;
    if (form2.Bottom >= sh) form2.Top = sh - form2.Height;
}
```

Just add one call to the `placeForm2` function to your button click as well..!

Note how I move the 2nd form from the left to the right, when you approach the right screen border. This is optional, of course..

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int frm1Width = this.Width;
        int frm1Top = this.Top;
        int frm1Left = this.Left;
        int delta = 15;

        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

        frm2.Show();
        frm2.Top = frm1Top;
        frm2.Left = frm1Left + frm1Width - delta;

    }
```

Comment: Does not handle form 1 movement or resize.